# JSON data array in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

So I am trying to pass json data to my `req.body`

The data looks like this:

```
answers = ["A","B"]; //This is an array that will be added to the JSON Object

var Student_Answers = { //This is the JSON object
   Answers: answers,
   matricNumber: matric
};
```

This is the post request:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: `/exam/${matric2}`,
      dataType: "json",
      data: Student_Answers,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("data received: ", data);
      }
    });
```

So the data got passed to the `req.body` successfully but my problem is how the data looks like in the `req.body` output, when I logged the `req.body` it looks like this:

```
 {
  'Answers[]': [ 'A', 'B' ],
  matricNumber: '88/2386'
}
```

But what I am expecting

```
 {
  Answers: [ 'A', 'B' ],
  matricNumber: '88/2386'
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the answers array is viewed that way in the `req.body` `('Answers[]': [ 'A', 'B' ])`.it is messing up my saving the data to mongodb.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataType` tells jQuery what kind of data you're expecting **back** in the response. To tell jQuery what kind of data you're **sending** in the request, set [`contentType`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). (And yes, it **is** confusing that `data` is the data to send, but `dataType` is the type of response you expect. API fail.  ) You also need to stringify it yourself, jQuery won't do it for you:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: `/exam/${matric2}`,
  contentType: "application/json",       // <===========
  data: JSON.stringify(Student_Answers), // <===========
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("data received: ", data);
  }
});
```

Comment: when i do that it just passes { } to the req.body

Comment: @leonardikeh - The above will definitely pass JSON for `Student_Answers` to the server. You probably need to reseach body parsing on Express (it's not automatic, see the ``body-parser` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)). But your question was about the client side of this; once you've had a go at the server side of it, if you're still stuck after doing your research, etc., post a question showing an [mcve] of your server-side handling of the JSON and we can help.

Comment: thank you very much, this helped a lot [link](npmjs.com/package/body-parser), i was using urlencodedParser instead of jsonParser to parse the data.

Comment: @leonardikeh - Nice one solving it! :-)